# Regex to replace parameter names by values

Tags: regex

I have a string that has a form:

`UPDATE "TABLE"."ITEMS" SET ITM_DESCR=:sqldevvalue WHERE ROWID = :sqldevgridrowid AND ORA_ROWSCN = :sqldevgridrowscn`

and its binding values as:
    `#1(11):Test Record #2(18):AAAG9IAAFAAAC0eAAB #3(7):7746161`

How can I construct a regular expression to replace the parameter names (starting with :) with their corresponding values and create a combined string that has the form:

`UPDATE "TABLE"."ITEMS" SET ITM_DESCR=Test Record WHERE ROWID = AAAG9IAAFAAAC0eAAB AND ORA_ROWSCN = 7746161`

Comment: Does it have to be a single regex? You could do something as simple as this: http://regex101.com/r/qZ6jW0/1 where really you're only replacing out the variable names for the values.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This kind of parameter notation, `:name`, is usually used so that the used DB library can do that stuff for you, using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple, naive regex:

```
:(\w+)
```

Replace the match with the value, `$1` contains the parameter name.

Here's a less naive attempt:

```
'(?:''|[^'])*'|:(\w+)
```

If `$1` is set, replace the match with the value (`$1` contains the paramter name), else do not replace. This version will let you handle situations like `WHERE column = 'some text :not_a_param more text'`

And... the *not naive* approach is to use prepared statements and SQL parameters with whatever SQL client you're using. This is the best option as it negates any risk of SQL injections if you do something wrong, and lets the DBMS cache the execution plan for your request.